How do I interpret multiple linear regression results as % change in dependent variable
Say I'm interpreting my MLR and writing about one of my independent variables and it is an index (0-1), the coefficient is 4.169* . My dependent variable is in units degrees celsius. How do I interpret this so that I can say "a % increase in this independent variable corresponds to a x% increase/reduction in the dependent variable"
Both my dependent and independent variables are linear scale (ie: no logs)
There is lots of information regarding doing this for log sclaes but I guess it is assumed intuitive for linear? Anyway help would be much appreciated!

In almost all applications, a percent change in degrees Celsius is misleading--and log degrees Celsius is almost uninterpretable.  Is this really your application, or are you just using it as a metaphor for your real situation?

I'm just trying to understand how it works - so lets say the dependent variable is unitless and scored between 0-3.9. How would I calculate the % change in this dependent variable given the info above about the independent variable within the model I am looking at?  Thanks for getting back to me so quick!

The % change will depend on the current level of the dependent variable, because your regression model only estimates the difference; and a difference of (say) +1 starting at a level of 1 is 100% but starting at a level of 2 is only 50%.

You don’t. You haven’t seen this interpretation discussed because it does not exist.
The interpretation on the linear scale is that, for a one-unit change in the input, there is a change in output equal to the coefficient. That is, if the current value is 100 and increases to 101, there is a change in output equal to the coefficient. Also, if the value is 200 and increases to 201, the change in output is that same coefficient. Despite the smaller percentage increase in the latter case, the change is the same.
Thus, the interpretation on the linear scale cannot be in terms of percentages.


if I take that coefficient as my change in dependent variable - could I calculate what that is as a % of the mean value of my dependent variable - and state that this % change is evaluated at the mean of that variable?
2.my other independent variables include oil rents, gas rents, coal rents, vulnerability index and public support. Is it bad practise to take the log of these to do the regression so I can get a % change in dependent variable?


@DavidSturgess for an outcome with possible negative values (like degrees Celsius) you certainly shouldn't do that, as noted in a comment on your question. With positive outcomes, calculations based on the mean outcome are misleadingly erroneous for combinations of predictors that don't correspond with the mean outcome. See this post for why experienced analysts typically avoid percents and percent changes. An exception is analysis of elasticity, for example in economics.

One more question, thanks for all your help. I have gdppc as a log in the model as an independent variable along with my other (linear (not log)) independent variables. Do I interpret this one differently - ie: using the 'Linear-log' method of dividing by 100 to get the increase in dependent variable resulting from a 1% increase in independent variable?

@DavidSturgess this page and its links discuss interpretation with different combinations of log-transformed predictor and outcome variables. Be careful: interpretation depends on the logarithmic base that you use and on approximations that only hold with small changes. In general, the interpretation of a coefficient for a predictor is the change in outcome for a 1-unit change in the predictor. If the predictor was transformed when presented to the model, then it's for a 1-unit change in the transformed scale.
